# How do you view the first non zero number in an NumPy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a cube a = numpy.array(n,n,n). The size will vary.

I want to look from the top, so down on the columns, which there are nxn of, and return an array (n,n) with the first non zero number you can 'see'.

This is like looking down on the array imagining zeros are holes.

I can use sum(a, axis=0) but this adds up any number below the first zero also. I want just the first number after a zero (or zero if there are n zeros in the column)

I hope this is clear enough to get some advice :)

Cheers, Paul

Comment: rephrase your question and add examples.

Comment: can you provide an explicit minimal example?

Answer (score -2):

You can find the element you searche with `np.where(a==0)`, if there is more than one, you can find the first index with `np.where(a==0)[0][0]` so to get the first number after a zero you should use `a[np.where(a==0)[0][0]+1]`

Comment: Please tell me where arr=5 comes into it, I only have an array A, shape (3,3,3)

Comment: Sorry I just copied another code for np.where and forgot to change this one, I edited my response

Comment: This actually crashers out no with index 0 out of bounds

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).